# PageAdapter Control in IOS

Tags: ios

In android pager adapter control is available

is there any third party controls available in IOS

[image]

Comment: I don't think, you need and 3rd party library. "Fragment A", "Fragment B" and "Fragment C" could be segments of an `UISegmentedControl` and the content can be displayed in an `UIPageViewController` (or just an `UIView` if you don't need an animation when switching from A to B)

Comment: u can use scrollview to create same as image

Comment: Checkout this code too.. [`MHTabBarController`](https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController)